# Redirect to protected resource or original/saved request after Servlet 3.0 HttpServletRequest#login() authentication?

Tags: java, authentication, jsf-2, glassfish-3, servlet-3.0

As expected, the login page loads when a protected/secure resource is requested:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>jdbc</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

I understand `j_security_check` will automatically forward to the protected/secure resource if authentication is successful:

```
<form method="post" action="j_security_check">
    <input type="text" name="j_username">
    <input type="password" name= "j_password">
</form>
```

However, I would like to allow users **to register** (or login) to continue so I've used `JSF 2.0: <h:form...`, `EL: #{loginBean.register()}...`, etc... and I'm authenticating programmatically with Servlet 3.0:

```
public void register() {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();

    try {
        // Register...

        request.login(this.username, this.password);

        // Redirect to the protected/secure resource...

    } catch (ServletException e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**How do I find out what that originally requested resource was?** Possibly:

- Get "saved request" from session *(container specific)*?
- Try access the "original request" somehow *(where)*?
- Anything related to the request dispatcher *(wild guess)*?
- Use the "referer" header *(bad idea)*?
- Create a server authentication module (SAM) *(not simple)*?

Any advice would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The login page is under the covers opened by a forward and the original request URI is available as request attribute with the name `javax.servlet.forward.request_uri`.

So:

```
String uri = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri");
```

or, more JSF-ish:

```
String uri = externalContext.getRequestMap().get("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri");
```

Comment: Hello, in my case, the log inform is shown with a redirect. I don't know how to force it be a forward so request_ui works. Being a redirect (I mean, in the browser, loginform.xhtml is shown, not the original page) I get an empty value for request_ui. Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks.